# Why is the model "head" kept falling down through the another model "chassis"?

Tags: gazebo-11

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

the code is here:

```
  <include>
  <uri>model://head</uri>
  <pose>0.090 0 0.16 0 0 0</pose>
  <name>head</name>
  </include>
  <joint name="head_joint" type="fixed">
  <child>head</child>
  <parent>chassis</parent>
  </joint>
  </model>
```

my chassis code is:

```
        <link name='chassis'>
        <pose>0 0 .1 0 0 0</pose>

        <collision name='collision'>
          <geometry>
            <box>
              <size>0.2159 0.1524 0.10795</size>
            </box>
          </geometry>
        </collision>

        <visual name='visual'>
          <geometry>
            <box>
              <size>0.2159 0.1524 0.10795</size>
            </box>
          </geometry>
        </visual>
      </link>
```

I don't get how it just go through the model. Did I used the wrong one or what? I linked head as a child with chassis as parent.

I wanted to attach head on the chassis firmly without letting it go through the chassis. Do you have any idea what to put?

I'm using Gazebo11

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/27239/why-is-the-model-%22head%22-kept-falling-down-through-the-another-model-%22chassis%22?/) by [kakcalu13](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/51973/kakcalu13/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 87 on 2021-08-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I no longer call other model. I added them in the same file and it's working now.

It's a glitch, apparently.

SDF to SDF

Closing this one

---

Originally posted by [kakcalu13](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/51973/kakcalu13/) with karma: 87 on 2021-08-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [azeey](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6889/azeey/) on 2021-08-12**:
If you run `gazebo --verbose`, you might get an error message indicating what went wrong. My guess is the joint `<child>` needs to be a link, but you gave it the name of a model.

**Comment by [kakcalu13](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/51973/kakcalu13/) on 2021-08-12**:
Thank you for your reply! Yeah, --verbose said there was no model exist. Not sure why, but it's whatever now since create the "head" within the same file worked.